# removing string "undefined" from output

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <script>
  var names = <?php print_r(json_encode($_SESSION['name'])); ?>;
  var lnames = <?php print_r(json_encode($_SESSION['lname'])); ?>;  
  var j=1;
  $("#add_driver").click(function () {  
    $( "#add_driver_section").replaceWith( "<div class='wrap-input100 
     validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100' data-validate = 'Enter Your First 
      Name'> <span class='label-input100'>Firstname *</span> <input 
     class='input100' type='text' name='name[]' placeholder='Enter Your First 
     Name ' value='"+ names[j] +"'></div><div class='wrap-input100 validate- 
     input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100' data-validate = 'Enter Your Last Name'> 
      <span class='label-input100'>Lastname *</span> <input class='input100' 
     type='text' name='lname[]' placeholder='Enter Your Last Name ' value='"+ 
     lnames[j] +"'></div>");    
      j++;}

   );
     </script>
```

here i 
want

to first check if `names[j]` is empty or not and only use it if it is not empty. currently when i run my code, if `names[j]` is empty, i get the string "undefined" as the output.
what is a simple way to do this?
[image: the output i am getting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just with :

```
let mystring = arr[i] || '';
```

In your case :

```
let str = "start of string" + (arr[i] || '') + "end of string";
```

Comment: I have edit my post for adapting the code in your situation.

Comment: You need to change here--> `placeholder='Enter Your First 
     Name ' value='"+ (names[j] || '')  +"'></div>`

Answer (score 1):

You can check with PHP if `$_SESSION[]` is empty or not:

```
$names = isset($_SESSION['name']) ? $_SESSION['name'] : [] ;
$lnames = isset($_SESSION['lname']) ? $_SESSION['lname'] : [] ;

var names = <?php echo (json_encode($names)); ?>;
var lnames = <?php echo (json_encode($lnames)); ?>;
```